# C++ Multidimensional Vector

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, vector, dynamic

how can I make a table like this with vector in C++:

```
65  A
66  B
67  C
```

I did it with a dynamic 2d array like this:

```
int** ary = new int*[2];
for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    ary[i] = new int[size];

// fill the array
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    ary[i][0] = ascii_values[i];

}
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    ary[i][1] = ascii_chars[i];

}
```

How can I do this with vector?
I was thinking of putting two vectors inside a third vector but I don`t know if that is possible.
P.s. everything has to be dynamic because I will import data from a file 
Please help :)

Comment: its actually not really multidimensional, but rather a list of `int, char` pairs. Thus the most natural would be a `std::vector<std::pair<int,char>>`

Comment: I have chars and ints in seperate vectors. 
vector<int> ascii_values      and        vector<char> ascii_chars 
How can I add them to the third one?

Comment: what third one? Give me a sec I will write an answer...

Comment: something like:
vector< pair < vector<int> ints , vector<char> chars > > thirdOne

Comment: @MarkoMlakar tobi303's suggestion is accurate. `std::vector<std::pair<int,char>>` is what your question's snippet seems to be trying to replicate. A vector is `size` elements, each element being a pair of values, the first being an `int` and the second being a `char`.

Comment: and how do I use it? Can you give me an example of printing a simple table like that please? :) It would help me alot thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily implement the behaviour above using a vector of `std::pair` . See the [demo](http://ideone.com/oD9KCX):

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
 std::vector<std::pair<int,char>> result;
 std::vector<int> ascii_vals {65, 66, 67};
 std::vector<char> ascii_chars {'a', 'b', 'c'};

 auto ItA = ascii_vals.begin();
 auto ItB = ascii_chars.begin();

 while(ItA != ascii_vals.end() && ItB != ascii_chars.end())
 {
    result.push_back(std::make_pair(*ItA,*ItB));

    if(ItA != ascii_vals.end())
    {
        ++ItA;
    }
    if(ItB != ascii_chars.end())
    {
        ++ItB;
    }
 }

 for(std::vector<std::pair<int, char> >::iterator it = result.begin(); it != result.end(); it++)
    std::cout << "(" << it->first << ", " << it->second << ")" << std::endl;

 return 0;
}
```

The code above will print:

```
(65, a)
(66, b)
(67, c)
```

Comment: @tobi303 how so? This is one of the standard ways to iterate over two containers at once without using the zip utility from Boost

Comment: if thats the standard way, then I learned something. However, I find it a bit strange to reuse the last element of the container with smaller size. Not sure but I think I would  not like it that the code results in same output for (1,2,3,4),(1,2) and (1,2,3,4),(1,2,2,2)

Comment: Ahh I see your concern, I just assumed both containers would be the same size, but yes maybe it would be best to change the condition to an &&

Comment: I found [this](https://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2005/07/90866.php) and what I understood is that also boots zip iterator expect the containers to be equal size (same as the std algorithms) and thats also what I would expect

Comment: Just one more question:p How can I display just the first one " 65  a " through result? If it was an array  it would have index result[0][0]. Is this correct?: cout << result[0].first  <<result[0].second ;

Comment: You want to use std::get, see this link for an example: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/get/

Answer (score 2):

Your data is actually not really multidimensional, but rather a list of `int, char` pairs. Thus the most natural would be a `std::vector<std::pair<int,char>>`. Imho whenever you can name a pair, you should do so, ie that would be

```
struct Foo {    // I cannot, but you can choose better names
     int x;
     char y;
};
```

And create a vector via

```
std::vector<Foo> f;
```

For how to use a vector I refer you to the massive amount of material that you can find online.

If however, you already have your data in two vectors, as you mentioned in a comment, then the easiest is probably to use some

```
struct Bar {
    std::vector<char> x;
    std::vector<int> y;
};
```

which may contain the same data, but depending on how you need to process the data it might be more or less efficient compared to the `std::vector<Foo>` (do you need to access the chars and ints independently or always as those pairs?).

Comment: Always as those pairs :)

Comment: @MarkoMlakar as I wrote, if you can name it, then dont use `std::pair`. If I remember correctly I heard Scott Meyers once giving this advice and to me it completely makes sense. Once you choose better names, `Foo` is much nicer then `pair` and `x`/`y` is nicer than `first`/`second`

Comment: @MarkoMlakar haha I only understood your comment after reading my ansewr again... then go for the `std::vector<Foo>`